# Form field dependency on one another in django

Tags: django-forms, django-formwizard

I have the below form field :

forms.py

```
class BuildForm(forms.Form):

   site_num  = forms.IntegerField(label=("No of Sites"))
   site_name = forms.CharField(label=("Site Name"))
```

I want that the field "site_name" should be displayed as per the integer value entered in the "site_num" field.
e.g: If the user enters 2 in "No of Sites" then two "site_name" fields should be displayed to enter two site names.

If I use a form wizard then the site_name field will be in another form and in that case how can i get the previous form data and process accordingly to show field as per the integer value.

Can anyone let me know, how can this be achieved ??

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED** :

I have overridden the get_form_kwargs method of my form wizard in views

view.py

```
class FormWizard(SessionWizardView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
        kwargs = {}
        if step == '2':
            site_num = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('1')['site_num']
            kwargs.update({'site_num': site_num,})
        return kwargs
```

and also the **init** function of my form with the site_name field.

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    #some fields

class MyForm1(forms.Form):
    site_num = forms.IntegerField()

class MyForm2(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        extra = kwargs.pop('site_num')
        super(MyForm2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(extra):
            self.fields['site_name_%s' % i] = forms.CharField()
```